# Ripple paper wallet: is "ripplepaperwallet.com" safe?

Tags: wallet, security, ripple, paper-wallet, trust

I've been reading on the internet and I have found several websites for generating Ripple paper wallets: ripply.eu, bithomp.com, gatehub, etc. I'm not sure if these websites are official Ripple websites and trustworthy for generating paper wallets.

So, I'm wondering whether https://www.ripplepaperwallet.com is an official and trustworthy website for generating wallets.

I'm using Windows 8.1 and the latest version of Google Chrome.

Answer (score 2):

Considering the fact it has iframes (e.g ads) in it and they might have access to the parent (e.g http://ripplepaperwallet.com) DOM, I would say that even if it was an open source project (which I have not found any references to) I would say it relies on a third party that is not open source therefore theoretically can be not safe.

As well, I did not see an offline version of it, which in my opinion is a good practice to verify integrity of paper wallets.

Comment: I concur that an offline version is important and a good sign of trustability.

Comment: @AchiEven-dar Thank you for your answer. And what could be an example of a trustworthy ripple paper wallet?

Comment: @Scott What is an offline version? Is that different from running the paper wallet generator while the internet connection is turned off? Is it different from saving the web page as an HTML file and opening that file with the internet connection turned off in order to generate wallets?

Comment: @UserX This specific wallet has no "create wallet" button. The keys come along with the page. So you can't use option A - running the page offline.    
Option B (save the html) should be the same as an offline version, but make sure you run it a few times and get different keys (while offline).    
That obviously doesn't give you full protection, The safest thing to do is obviously debug the code and see if you find anything that might be not secure (while offline) and send a small amount to begin with.
I am not a big fan of Ripple at the moment, but heard Rippex is ok.

Comment: @UserX, Yes, by "offline version", I mean a paper wallet generator that can run without an internet connection.  It needs to generate many keys and can't be "hardcoded" to predetermined keys (check source code).  I would not recommend saving the web page as an HTML file as you could be saving something intended and/or functional.

Comment: @AchiEven-dar "This specific wallet has no "create wallet" button. The keys come along with the page. So you can't use option A - running the page offline." Sorry for my ignorance, but I was able to generate pairs of public and private keys at ripplepaperwallet.com while my internet connection was turned off. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Scott "It needs to generate many keys and can't be "hardcoded" to predetermined keys (check source code). I would not recommend saving the web page as an HTML file as you could be saving something intended and/or functional." What does this mean?

Comment: @UserX Sorry you are right, I didn't see the "Generate New" button. I'm leaving my previous answer for "educational purposes". Either way I would suggest as well to open in "incognito mode" to disable browser extensions that might track you. In case you don't want to download the html and run it you can debug it i the browser, put a "debugger" in the onclick function e.g    
 `<button onclick="debugger;generate()" title="Generate new">Generate New</button>`

Comment: @UserX, here is an example of an offline wallet, but for Bitcoin: https://bitcoinpaperwallet.com/#popupZip  All of the source is available on Github.  This is the preferred way of getting an offline version if Ripple had its own version like this.

Answer (score 0):

- if I generate a new address on RipplePaperWallet and transfer my XRP to the address I just generated then:

  1. Is safely stored away offline using that address and secret key if necessary?
  2. If I do nothing else after that, these XRP are essentially stored safely offline? Nothing is online or tied specifically to RipplePaperWallet site?